# How can I trace a traffic and IO spike every morning on my webserver?

Tags: web-server, log-files

Every morning (for about 2 weeks now), around 6:30 am, I get a large IO and incoming-traffic spike on my webserver. It didn't happen until a few days after I released my site. As I'm still a bit of a novice when it comes to server management, I was wondering how I would find out what causes it? It seems like a DoS attack but it seems odd that it happens at the same time every single day.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Server, PHP, Apache2.

Comment: If someone can upvote, I will add images.

Answer (score 1):

If the spike at exactly same time  I'd examine cron jobs (jobs run at specific time by server) as well as "pseudo cron jobs" - same as above, just implemented in software running the site and fired when handling user request around defined time.

Comment: It started about a week after the site was launched so I doubt it's a cron issue - but I will double check.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Apache access log. Look at the User Agent, it's probably a spider (e.g. Googlebot) indexing your site.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for filtering this? It's a horrifically long file.

Comment: I checked manually and there really aren't that many queries.